# FirebaseAnimatedList initial scroll position

Tags: flutter

I have a chat app, so I would like to show the last messages when we open the conversation. I have initialized a ScrollController (and attached it to my FirebaseAnimatedList) and tried this :

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      if (controller.hasClients) {
        print("message");
        controller.jumpTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
      }
    });
  }
```

It doesn't work, and doesn't print "message".

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the `reverse` property of `FirebaseAnimatedList` class by setting **true**.